# Segmentation fault with C++ and consteval

Tags: c++, c++20

The following small example of C++20 code gives a segmentation fault when run. Why?

If I create an object of class **Implementation** and call the consteval function **implementation.foo()** it returns 42 as expected. However if I create a reference of type **Interface** and call the consteval function **interface.foo()** I get a segmentation fault. I am missing something in why this would happen.

```
// Compile with
//
// g++ -std=c++20 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic consteval.cpp -o consteval

#include <iostream>

struct Interface
{
        virtual consteval int foo(void) = 0;
};

struct Implementation final : public Interface
{
        consteval int foo(void) override { return 42; }
};

int main(void)
{
        Implementation implementation;

        std::cout << "implementation.foo() returns: " << implementation.foo() << std::endl;

        Interface& interface = implementation;

        std::cout << "interface.foo() returns: " << interface.foo() << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Link to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:12,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:51,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:8,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:51,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:8,startLineNumber:3),source:%27//+Compile+with%0A//%0A//+g%2B%2B+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Werror+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic+consteval.cpp+-o+consteval%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Astruct+Interface%0A%7B%0A++++++++virtual+consteval+int+foo(void)+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Implementation+final+:+public+Interface%0A%7B%0A++++++++consteval+int+foo(void)+override+%7B+return+42%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++++++Implementation+implementation%3B%0A%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22implementation.foo()+returns:+%22+%3C%3C+implementation.foo()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++++++Interface%26+interface+%3D+implementation%3B%0A%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22interface.foo()+returns:+%22+%3C%3C+interface.foo()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.136239677523925,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Werror+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.511445767754616,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:26.352314554721474,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Polymorphism using virtual functions is a run-time only thing, while [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) functions are required to produce a compile-time result. It's simply not possible to combine those two concepts.

Comment: Regarding the why, you can use a debugger to look where it crashed exactly. Clang does not accept this code with reasonable errors so I think this is gcc bug.

Comment: Compiles without errors by gcc 12.2.1

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What? You can perfectly well have a `consteval virtual` function and call it polymorphically, *as long as all that still happens at compile time*.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should not compile. I believe it is a bug in GCC that it tries to compile it and the weird segfault is just a consequence.

`foo` is `consteval`, so every usage of it must be part of a constant expression. But here you use it as `interface.foo()`, where `interface` is not a core constant expression (and `foo` is not static), so `interface.foo()` can't possibly be a constant expression. Thus your code is invalid and should simply fail with a compiler error (but should neither segfault nor "work" as it did in the comments; that's just GCC's fault).

If you correct the code to make the call valid, then you should get the right result. You could, say, wrap the thing in a `constexpr` function

```
consteval int example() {
   Implementation impl;
   Interface &intf = impl;
   return intf.foo();
}
int main() { std::cout << example() << "\n"; }
```

This [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/K19YM635d) on current GCC.

Another way to get to correct code is to make the `Implementation` object `constexpr static` and `foo` `const`-qualified:

```
struct Interface {
        virtual consteval int foo(void) const = 0; // constexpr objects are const, so need const-qual to call foo
};

struct Implementation final : public Interface {
        consteval int foo(void) const override { return 42; }
};
int main() {
    constexpr static Implementation impl; // need static to form constant expression references ("the address of impl is now constexpr")
    Interface const &intf = impl; // this reference is automatically usable in constant expressions (being of reference type and constant-initialized), note that it is to a *const* Interface, requiring the change to foo
    std::cout << intf.foo() << "\n";
}
```

GCC still chokes on this one and produces a segfault, but [Clang produces](https://godbolt.org/z/6dvs6q9db) the expected result. Again, I suspect a GCC bug.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I guess I just didn't expect a bug in GCC to be the reason for not initially seeing that my code is invalid C++20.